# How to compute the width of a pulse in a waveform?

Tags: r

I need to compute the width of a pulse in the waveform. These pulses occur throughout the waveform.

I am trying to compute the difference between two consecutive values & if it exceeds a value (say a number) then I would identify that point as starting point of the pulse & find a point where it reaches the same level as before & I would consider that as end point of pulse. Once I have both the start & end point i would then compute the width (here it is number of points between those two points)

Comment: What do you mean to find a point where it reaches the same level as before? Is it greater than and equal to the start point?

Comment: Regarding the plot, I'd say same level means `>=`.

Comment: `sum(wave < median(wave))` This wouldn't work?

Comment: @ Darren, Yes liek I said, from one point it drastically falls down to a negattive value and then after minor oscillations it again reaches closer to the point where it had fallen from before..Hope I am able to answeer your query
please look at the image where it falls down initially in the begining of the pulse & how it again reaches closer to teh point again wehere it was before.

Comment: Here are relevant posts to detect "peaks/valleys": https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/how-to-find-local-peaks-valleys-in-a-series-of-data and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139660/detecting-changes-in-time-series-r-example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36309/how-do-i-find-peaks-in-a-dataset

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341717/detecting-cycle-maxima-peaks-in-noisy-time-series-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with a generic `for()` loop. Please note that this will probably be slow and ineffective for big data.

```
# example vector
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 1, 2, 1, -25, -23, -24, -25, -24, -23, -26, -23, -17, -11, 2, 1, 1, 2)

# initialize data frame with columns start (starting position of pulse), end (end position of pulse) and width (width of pulse)
pulsewidth <- data.frame(start = numeric(),
                         end = numeric(),
                         width = numeric())

# initialize temporary saving element for starting position
temp <- NA

# loop over position 2 to end of vector, compare lagged values, store position if pulse starts
for(i in 2:length(x)){
  if(abs(x[i] - x[i-1]) >= 25){
    temp <- i-1 # here you could use temp <- i instead, depending on your definition
  }
  if(!is.na(temp)){
    if(x[i] >= x[temp]){
      pulsewidth[nrow(pulsewidth)+1,] <- c(temp, i, i - temp)
      temp <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
> pulsewidth
  start end width
1     8  19    11
```

Comment: Thanks this helps me with above problem when there are no local minima & maxima. However in a non-utopian world, how would we address the problem when local minima/maxima are present.. Can I post this as separate question with more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 2):

`ggpmisc()` could offer some solution. Needs a little bit optimization in `span` value

```r
wave <- c(1, 2, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 1, 2, 1, -25, -23, -24, -25, -24, -23, -26, -23, -17, -11, 2, 1, 1, 2)
wave = data.frame(wave = wave)

library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.5.2
library(ggpmisc)
#> For news about 'ggpmisc', please, see https://www.r4photobiology.info/
#> For on-line documentation see https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/

with_valley <- 
   ggplot_build(
     ggplot(wave, aes(seq_along(wave), wave)) + geom_line() +
  stat_valleys(aes(seq_along(wave), wave), span = 10) 
   )
#> span increased to next odd value:  11


values <- with_valley$data[[2]]

values[2,"xintercept"]-values[1,"xintercept"]
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility of solving the task using `vapply`

```
starting_points <- which(c(abs(diff(pulse)) > 25L, FALSE))
res <- vapply(starting_points, function (k) {
  starting_value <- pulse[k]
  end_point <- min(intersect(which(pulse == starting_value), (k+1):length(pulse)))
  width <- end_point - k + 1
  c(start = k, end = end_point, width = width)
}, numeric(3))

# Results
res
#       [,1]
# start    8
# end     20
# width   13

# And here is result with a little more data
# setting pulse <- rep(pulse, 3L)
t(res)
#      start end width
# [1,]     8  20    13
# [2,]    30  42    13
# [3,]    52  64    13
```

wirh the data

```
pulse <- c(1, 2, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 1, 2, 1, -25, -23, -24, -25, -24, -23, -26, -23, -17, -11, 2, 1, 1, 2)
```